# Datatable - Sorting bad data result

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a problem when i try to sort my datatable,

You can see below my problem :

Before Sort :
[image]

After Sort :
[image]

When i try to sort my datatables, he sort but he add my last data below the new data.

```
    // Définition de l'objet datatable
$("#dataTable").dataTable({  "aaData": data,
"aoColumns": title,
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": false,
"bSort": true,
"bSortClasses": false,
"bPaginate": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bJQueryUI": false,
"aLengthMenu": [10, 15, 25, 50, 100],
"iDisplayLength": 15,
"oLanguage": {
    "sProcessing":   "<?=$DataTablesProcessing;?>",
    "sLengthMenu":   "<?=$DataTablesLengthMenu;?>",
    "sZeroRecords":  "<?=$DataTablesZeroRecords;?>",
    "sInfo":         "<?=$DataTablesInfo;?>",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "<?=$DataTablesInfoEmpty;?>",
    "sInfoFiltered": "<?=$DataTablesInfoFiltered;?>",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "<?=$DataTablesInfoPostFix;?>",
    "sSearch":       "<?=$DataTablesSearch;?>",
    "sUrl":          "<?=$DataTablesUrl;?>",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "<?=$DataTableoPaginatesFirst;?>",
        "sPrevious": "<?=$DataTableoPaginatesPrevious;?>",
        "sNext":     "<?=$DataTableoPaginatesNext;?>",
        "sLast":     "<?=$DataTableoPaginatesLast;?>"
    }
}
```

});

If you have any idea for this problem.

I tryed to create my table in html but that change nothing.

BR

Comment: what is 'title' for "aoColumns": title?

Comment: It's my variable who contain all column's name.

Comment: please post title variable with values .. so that we can help you better

Comment: You can find my title and data here : http://pastebin.com/wD2CNq57

Comment: try adding '"bSortable": true' for each value in title array, like titre[0] = {"sTitle" : "Centre", "bSortable": true};

Comment: I tryed and i have the same problem =( I have no idea ... :(

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: I have no error in my console (firebug and chrome)

Comment: I make all in html and the problem come when I use a <th> for my columns title, when I use <td> for the head, I have no problem and I can sort. Any idea ? I have deleted all css but i have the error too